# Is there a way to use Python to check the url of the currently opened browser?

Tags: python, url, browser

I wanted to write a program that continuously checks the URL of a browser (e.g. Chrome) and if it is equal to `www.youtube.com`, then I want to switch the URL. I'm stuck on trying to find a way to check the URL of a currently opened browser. Is the webbrowser module only for opening new browsers?

Edit: What I've tried so far is webbrowser:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com')
```

Comment: If you show attempts you've made so far you have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I've updated with what I tried so far. I'm new to using python with web browsers :)

Comment: As far as I know (and have just looked up) you can only open new tabs/urls in the browser, with the webbrowser package. However I don't think that python is the best programming language for this. Surly there's a way if you embed C in Python, but I doubt this is what you want to do. Why don't you program your program as an addon for the browser?